# Prove, using the mean value theorem, that $x+1 \lt e^x \lt xe^x+1$ for $x \gt 0$

Tags: calculus

Prove, using the mean value theorem, that $x+1 \lt e^x \lt xe^x+1$ for $x \gt 0$.

What I tried so far: Let there be a function $f(x)=xe^x$. So $f'(x)=xe^x+e^x$. Let there be arbitrary interval $(0,b)$. So by the mean value theorem there is $c \in (0,b)$ so that:
$f'(c)= \frac{f(b)-f(0)}{b-0}$, thus $ce^c+e^c=\frac{be^b}{b}=e^b$.

So $e^c(c+1)=e^b$. So $c+1 \lt e^b$, but I don't really know how to continue.

Any **hints** will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $$x+1 \lt e^x \lt xe^x+1 \iff 1 \lt \frac{e^x-e^0}{x - 0} \lt e^x$$

Now can you apply the Mean-Value Theorem?

Comment: We just call the interval $(0,x)$ and thus, for some $c \in (0,x)$, we get that $ce^c+e^c=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$. Since $c>0$, $e^c>1$, so $1 \lt ce^c+e^c=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$.

Comment: @Reyo $(xe^{x})' = xe^x+e^x$, but we are not applying MVT to that function. Apply it on $e^t$ in the interval $(0,x)$, then $\exists \, c \in (0,x)$, such that $e^{c} = \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$, now $c \in (0,x) \implies e^0 < e^c < e^x$.

Comment: but why? What I did also gives the correct result, or did I do something wrong? For the other side, since $1 \lt \frac{e^x-1}{x}$ we can say that $\frac{e^x-1}{x} \lt e^x-1 \lt e^x$.

Comment: @Reyo I'm not sure how you got $ce^c+e^c=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ .. and neither your next comment, it's best if you add your steps in the question body so I can understand what's going on.

Comment: Oops, my bad! Got confused :(

Comment: @Reyo no problem! happens with all of us.